# jquery ajax works with version 1.4.1 but same function is not working with jquery 1.90

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Below is the ajax function which i am calling on click of a link.Below is the code for the same. when i run this function with jquery 1.4 version it displays the data perfectly. but on running the same code with jquery 1.9 i can see that ajax call is successful but the data is not displayed in the page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text json",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "pageList.php",
    data: $.parseJSON(test2),
    //  data: test ,
    //data:dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("hiii");
        $(".flash").hide();
        $(".link a").css('background-color', '#fff');
        $("#" + liId + " a").css('border-color', '#a84444');
        $("#" + liId).addClass('test');
        $("#pageData").html(result);
        $("#" + liId).show();
        $("#first,#last,#pev,#next").show();
        $(back_show).show();
        $(front_show).show();
        alert('Load was performed.');

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the value and data type of `test2`? Is the `success` handler executed at all? If you don't provide information about your debugging attempts, it's more difficult for us to help you.

Comment: test2 is an json object whihc contains two elements, one an integrer and another short text required for the ajax call

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) ... what does `typeof test2` return?

Comment: @Felix Kling : for jquery 1.9 version success call doesnt get executed

Comment: myObj["pid"] = "This is test";
myObj["pageId"] = pageId;
var test2 = JSON.stringify(myObj);

Comment: Ah, ok, so you are indeed passing a string containing JSON. I was asking because since jQuery 1.9, `$.parseJSON` throws an error if you don't pass a string containing JSON. However, you can just omit the whole to JSON/from JSON step and do `data: myObj`. There is no reason to convert the object to JSON if you immediately parse it again. Any errors in the console? *"i can see that ajax call is successful but the data is not displayed in the page."* How do you verify that the call is successful?

Comment: in firebug i can see the response of the ajax call. but the success function does not get called. i dont even get the aler ("hii")

Comment: Firstly, is this a type-o: `dataType: "text json",`. Secondly, please try putting a handler into the `complete` callback and debugging both the xhr and the result in that function.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!! changing the datatype worked

Answer (score 0):

First thing I observed in your code that you set dataType to "text json" that means you are expecting text data from server and jquery convert it to json. However in your success function you treat result as html ($("#pageData").html(result);).

So I think you need to be clear with what result is returned from server and how you want to use that result.

And important thing is that multiple data types are supported as of jQuery 1.5 only. See [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of dataType option.

> multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert
>   a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what
>   you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as
>   XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP
>   request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML:
>   "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml"
>   will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that,
>   convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.